# How to connect to ldap in dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, authentication, dart, active-directory, ldap

**Hello,**

I tried to connect my flutter app with my company's active directory but it didn't work. I need one thing, just to know is credentials are correct and connection can be established, nothing more.
I found **[dartdap](https://pub.dev/packages/dartdap)** and other [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838663/dartlang-and-dartdap-library-and-connection-to-active-directory) on stackoverflow but it doesn't help.

**My code is:**

```
    var host = '10.1.1.5';
    var login = 'myLogin'; //loginController.text;
    var password = 'myPassword'; //passController.text;
    var port = 389;

    var connection = new LdapConnection(host: host, ssl: false, port: port, bindDN: login, password: password);


    try {

      await connection.open();      
      await connection.bind();
      print('Bind OK');
    } catch (e, stacktrace) {
      print('********* Exception: $e, Stacktrace: $stacktrace');
    } finally {     
      print('Closing');
      await connection.close();
    }
  }
```

**And I tried with this config:**

```
    var host = '10.1.1.5';
    var login = 'mylogin'; //
    var base = 'DC=I,DC=domain,DC=com';
    var bindDN = "cn=" + login + ","  + base;
    var password = 'mypassword'; //passController.text;
    var port = 389;
```

And when I want to connect, I got response with Invalid Credentials in both situations.

```
I/flutter (10334): ********* Exception: Invalid credentials80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09044E, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580
```

That credentials are 100% correct, but data 52e means: Returns when username is valid but password/credential is invalid. (from [ldapwiki](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors)).

I haven't got any ideas, please *help* mates :(

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that your bind DN is correct? In Active Directory it's unlikely to have user login directly under base DN without a container like `CN=Users`. You need to provide a distinguished name, I would run `Get-ADUser mylogin` in the PowerShell and use DistinguishedName exactly as returned. Alternatively, you can log in using UPN, so e.g., if your account is named `mylogin`, you should be able to bind as `mylogin@I.domain.com`.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that port 389 is open on firewall?

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."